# Group objects not working in my detail view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to access the group object from detail view, but for one reason its  not rendering the objects to my HTML template, in detail view, except the group name, but i want as well to be able to render the group cover image and group users. I would appreciate some help. Here is my detail view.

```
def group_main(request, pk):
    context= {}
    group = get_object_or_404(Group,pk=pk)
    context['group'] = group
    return render(request,'group/grouptimeline.html',context)
```

Here is the model

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group = models.OneToOneField(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='groups')
    member = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="members" )
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='group_cover')
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='path/post/img' ,blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This is part of my  detail html template which only render the group name, but i can't access the
group cover picture and users.

```
<div class="main_content">
            <div class="mcontainer">

                <div class="profile is_group">
                  
                    <div class="profiles_banner">
                        <img src="{{ group.name.cover.url }}" alt="">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="profiles_content">

                        <div class="profile_info">
                            <h1> {{ group.name }} </h1>
                            <p> Public group ·  12k members</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex items-center space-x-4">
                            <div class="flex items-center -space-x-4">
                                <img src="assets/images/avatars/avatar-5.jpg" alt="" class="w-10 h-10 rounded-full border-2 border-white">
                                <img src="assets/images/avatars/avatar-6.jpg" alt="" class="w-10 h-10 rounded-full border-2 border-white">
                                <div class="w-10 h-10 rounded-full flex justify-center items-center bg-red-100 text-red-500 font-semibold"> 12+
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        
                            <a href="#" class="flex items-center justify-center h-9 px-5 rounded-md bg-blue-600 text-white  space-x-1.5">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" class="w-5">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                        d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zm1-11a1 1 0 10-2 0v2H7a1 1 0 100 2h2v2a1 1 0 102 0v-2h2a1 1 0 100-2h-2V7z"
                                        clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                </svg>
                                <span> Join </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                     
                    </div>
```

Comment: Why does `Group` has a `OneToOneField` to `Group`?

Comment: I'm using a OnetoOne field to  store information related to User, you can use a one-to-one relationship to a model containing the fields for additional information. This one-to-one model is often called a profile model, as it might store non-auth related information about a site user. and if  the changes you need are purely behavioral, and don’t require any change to what is stored in the database, you can create a proxy model based on User. that's basically what i did.@WillemVanOnsem

Comment: but I'm not concerned about the link to the `User`, but more the `group = models.OneToOneField(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='groups')` so to the `Group`. This can not refer to the same object, since at that moment the class does not yet exists. So it is referring to another `Group` model, likely the builtin one.

Comment: Yeah I used that because i wanted to create a proxy model base for the group users that's why I used the one to one field. so that I can i have additional information about group user, what do you suggest that i make it a ForeignKeyField ? here  is a link on creating proxy models  with OneToOne 
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model  @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: And still the Cover image won't render in my HTML trying <img src="{{ group.cover.url }}" alt=""> @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: did you implement static and media urls and views? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: as for the proxy model, this is not a proxy model. A proxy model has as `Meta` `proxy=True` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#proxy-models). This is simply a "profile model" since it creates a new table, and while these are sometimes useful, it often results in more complicated queries, and lower database performance.

Comment: Yes i did and on the list view everything works there, perfectly. The cover picture actually shows and number of users. when i loop through the groups. {% for g in groups.all %}, but the case is different in detail view, since i don't need a for loop so it doesn't show the group image.

Comment: did you import the correct `Group`, since you have a `Group` from the `django.contrib.auth.models` named `Group` and one in your own application. I would avoid naming these *both* `Group`, and thus for example rename your model `GroupDetail`.

Comment: Okay i guess that might be the problem , let me try renaming and then i will let you know!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it finally worked it was actually the import group name that was coursing me all the trouble but after i had change the name it worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise to rename your model to `GroupDetail`, since not it will generate a lot of confusion since there are two models used: the `Group` from the `django.contrib.auth.models`, and the one you defined yourself.

Likely it is better to implement this as:

```
class GroupDetail(models.Model):
    group = models.OneToOneField(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='groups')
    # …
```

Then in the view, we can fetch the `GroupDetail`s for a primary key with:

```
group = get_object_or_404(GroupDetail, pk=pk)
```

or if we want to work with the primary key of the referenced `Group` model, then it is:

```
group = get_object_or_404(GroupDetail, group__pk=pk)
```

This thus means that the view should look like:

```
def group_main(request, pk):
    context= {
        'groupdetail': get_object_or_404(GroupDetail, group__pk=pk)
    }
    return render(request,'group/grouptimeline.html',context)
```

Furthermore, you are rendering the `GroupDetail` object with variables that do not exist on the `Group` object. You should render these with:

```
<img src="{{ groupdetail.cover.url }}" alt="">
<!-- … -->
<h1> {{ groupdetail.group_name }} </h1>
```